# How to resolve ERROR: Could not build wheels for hdbscan, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, bert-language-model, hdbscan

I am trying to install bertopic and I got this error:

```
 pip install bertopic

 

    Collecting bertopic
>           Using cached bertopic-0.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
>         Collecting hdbscan>=0.8.28
>           Using cached hdbscan-0.8.28.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
>           Installing build dependencies: started
>           Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
>           Getting requirements to build wheel: started
>           Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
>           Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
>           Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
>         Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.41.1 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bertopic) (4.62.3)
>         Collecting umap-learn>=0.5.0
>           Using cached umap_learn-0.5.3-py3-none-any.whl
>         Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.22.2.post1 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bertopic)
> 
(0.24.2)
>     

    Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.20.0 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bertopic)
> (1.20.3)
>         Collecting plotly>=4.7.0
>           Using cached plotly-5.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15.2 MB)
>         Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.1.5 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from bertopic)
> (1.3.4)
>         Collecting pyyaml<6.0
>         Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
>           error: subprocess-exited-with-error


 >           

>       

        Building wheel for hdbscan (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
>           exit code: 1
>           
>           [40 lines of output]
>           running bdist_wheel
>           running build
>           running build_py
>           creating build
>           creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
>           creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan
>           copying hdbscan\flat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan
>           copying hdbscan\hdbscan_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan
>           copying hdbscan\plots.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan
>           copying hdbscan\prediction.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan
>           copying hdbscan\robust_single_linkage_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan
>           copying hdbscan\validity.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan
>           copying hdbscan\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan
>           creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan\tests
>           copying hdbscan\tests\test_flat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan\tests
>           copying hdbscan\tests\test_hdbscan.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan\tests
>           copying hdbscan\tests\test_prediction_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan\tests
>           copying hdbscan\tests\test_rsl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan\tests
>           copying hdbscan\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan\tests
>           running build_ext
>           cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_tree.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_tree.c
>           C:\Users\Martin Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a026odlf\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369:
> FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for
> now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Martin
> Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r29izqw\hdbscan_215c105aa4414866a73cfee4bf64c07a\hdbscan\_hdbscan_tree.pyx
>             tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
>           cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_linkage.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_linkage.c
>           C:\Users\Martin Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a026odlf\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369:
> FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for
> now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Martin
> Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r29izqw\hdbscan_215c105aa4414866a73cfee4bf64c07a\hdbscan\_hdbscan_linkage.pyx
>             tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
>           cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_boruvka.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_boruvka.c
>           C:\Users\Martin Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a026odlf\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369:
> FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for
> now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Martin
> Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r29izqw\hdbscan_215c105aa4414866a73cfee4bf64c07a\hdbscan\_hdbscan_boruvka.pyx
>             tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
>           cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_reachability.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_reachability.c
>           C:\Users\Martin Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a026odlf\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369:
> FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for
> now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Martin
> Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r29izqw\hdbscan_215c105aa4414866a73cfee4bf64c07a\hdbscan\_hdbscan_reachability.pyx
>             tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
>           cythoning hdbscan/_prediction_utils.pyx to hdbscan\_prediction_utils.c
>           C:\Users\Martin Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a026odlf\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369:
> FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for
> now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Martin
> Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r29izqw\hdbscan_215c105aa4414866a73cfee4bf64c07a\hdbscan\_prediction_utils.pyx
>             tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
>           cythoning hdbscan/dist_metrics.pyx to hdbscan\dist_metrics.c
>           C:\Users\Martin Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a026odlf\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369:
> FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for
> now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Martin
> Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2r29izqw\hdbscan_215c105aa4414866a73cfee4bf64c07a\hdbscan\dist_metrics.pxd
>             tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
>           Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (213 kB)
>         Collecting sentence-transformers>=0.4.1
>           Using cached sentence_transformers-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl
>         Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan>=0.8.28->bertopic)
> (1.7.1)
>         Requirement already satisfied: cython>=0.27 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan>=0.8.28->bertopic)
> (0.29.28)
>         Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=1.0 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan>=0.8.28->bertopic)
> (1.1.0)
>         Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
> pandas>=1.1.5->bertopic) (2.8.2)
>         Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=1.1.5->bertopic)
> (2021.3)
>         Collecting tenacity>=6.2.0
>           Using cached tenacity-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
>         Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
> scikit-learn>=0.22.2.post1->bertopic) (2.2.0)
>         Collecting torch>=1.6.0
>           Using cached torch-1.12.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (161.8 MB)
>         Collecting sentencepiece
>           Using cached sentencepiece-0.1.96-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (1.1 MB)
>         Requirement already satisfied: nltk in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
> sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (3.6.5)
>         Collecting torchvision
>           Using cached torchvision-0.13.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (1.1 MB)
>         Collecting transformers<5.0.0,>=4.6.0
>           Using cached transformers-4.21.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 MB)
>         Collecting huggingface-hub>=0.4.0
>           Using cached huggingface_hub-0.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
>         Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from tqdm>=4.41.1->bertopic)
> (0.4.4)
>         Collecting pynndescent>=0.5
>           Using cached pynndescent-0.5.7-py3-none-any.whl
>         Requirement already satisfied: numba>=0.49 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from umap-learn>=0.5.0->bertopic)
> (0.54.1)
>         Requirement already satisfied: filelock in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
> huggingface-hub>=0.4.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic)
> (3.3.1)
>         Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.7.4.3 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
> huggingface-hub>=0.4.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic)
> (3.10.0.2)
>         Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
> huggingface-hub>=0.4.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic)
> (2.27.1)
>         Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.9 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
> huggingface-hub>=0.4.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (21.0)
>         Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
> numba>=0.49->umap-learn>=0.5.0->bertopic) (58.0.4)
>         Requirement already satisfied: llvmlite<0.38,>=0.37.0rc1 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
> numba>=0.49->umap-learn>=0.5.0->bertopic) (0.37.0)
>         Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
> python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas>=1.1.5->bertopic) (1.16.0)
>         Requirement already satisfied: regex!=2019.12.17 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
> transformers<5.0.0,>=4.6.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic)
> (2021.8.3)
>         Collecting tokenizers!=0.11.3,<0.13,>=0.11.1
>           Using cached tokenizers-0.12.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (3.3 MB)
>         Requirement already satisfied: click in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
> nltk->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (7.1.2)
>         Requirement already satisfied: pillow!=8.3.*,>=5.3.0 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
> torchvision->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (8.4.0)
>         Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
> packaging>=20.9->huggingface-hub>=0.4.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic) (3.0.4)
>         Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
> requests->huggingface-hub>=0.4.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic)
> (2.0.4)
>         Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
> requests->huggingface-hub>=0.4.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic)
> (2021.10.8)
>         Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
> requests->huggingface-hub>=0.4.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic)
> (3.2)
>         Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
> requests->huggingface-hub>=0.4.0->sentence-transformers>=0.4.1->bertopic)
> (1.26.7)
>         Building wheels for collected packages: hdbscan
>           Building wheel for hdbscan (pyproject.toml): started
>           Building wheel for hdbscan (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
>         Failed to build hdbscan
>           building 'hdbscan._hdbscan_tree' extension
>           error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
>           [end of output]
>           
>           note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
>           ERROR: Failed building wheel for hdbscan
>         ERROR: Could not build wheels for hdbscan, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x86) - 14.32.31332 installed. I have upgraded my pip as well `pip-22.2.1`

I tried installing hdbscan and I also got an error:

```
pip install hdbscan
  

> Collecting hdbscan
>       Using cached hdbscan-0.8.28.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
>       Installing build dependencies: started
>       Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
>       Getting requirements to build wheel: started
>       Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
>       Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
>       Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
>     Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.20 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan)
> (0.24.2)
>     Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=1.0 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan) (1.1.0)
>     Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan) (1.7.1)
>     Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.20 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan) (1.20.3)
>     Requirement already satisfied: cython>=0.27 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from hdbscan) (0.29.28)
>     Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\users\martin kunth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
> scikit-learn>=0.20->hdbscan) (2.2.0)
>     Building wheels for collected packages: hdbscan
>       Building wheel for hdbscan (pyproject.toml): started
>       Building wheel for hdbscan (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
>     Failed to build hdbscan
>     Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
>       error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>       
>       Building wheel for hdbscan (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
>       exit code: 1
>       
>       [40 lines of output]
>       running bdist_wheel
>       running build
>       running build_py
>       creating build
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan
>       copying hdbscan\flat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan
>       copying hdbscan\hdbscan_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan
>       copying hdbscan\plots.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan
>       copying hdbscan\prediction.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan
>       copying hdbscan\robust_single_linkage_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan
>       copying hdbscan\validity.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan
>       copying hdbscan\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan
>       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan\tests
>       copying hdbscan\tests\test_flat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan\tests
>       copying hdbscan\tests\test_hdbscan.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan\tests
>       copying hdbscan\tests\test_prediction_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan\tests
>       copying hdbscan\tests\test_rsl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan\tests
>       copying hdbscan\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\hdbscan\tests
>       running build_ext
>       cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_tree.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_tree.c
>       C:\Users\Martin Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cn18pe9m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369:
> FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for
> now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Martin
> Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k2_bwg0z\hdbscan_9b50b30873a2465bb3156fb27111abf2\hdbscan\_hdbscan_tree.pyx
>         tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
>       cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_linkage.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_linkage.c
>       C:\Users\Martin Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cn18pe9m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369:
> FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for
> now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Martin
> Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k2_bwg0z\hdbscan_9b50b30873a2465bb3156fb27111abf2\hdbscan\_hdbscan_linkage.pyx
>         tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
>       cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_boruvka.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_boruvka.c
>       C:\Users\Martin Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cn18pe9m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369:
> FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for
> now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Martin
> Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k2_bwg0z\hdbscan_9b50b30873a2465bb3156fb27111abf2\hdbscan\_hdbscan_boruvka.pyx
>         tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
>       cythoning hdbscan/_hdbscan_reachability.pyx to hdbscan\_hdbscan_reachability.c
>       C:\Users\Martin Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cn18pe9m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369:
> FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for
> now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Martin
> Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k2_bwg0z\hdbscan_9b50b30873a2465bb3156fb27111abf2\hdbscan\_hdbscan_reachability.pyx
>         tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
>       cythoning hdbscan/_prediction_utils.pyx to hdbscan\_prediction_utils.c
>       C:\Users\Martin Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cn18pe9m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369:
> FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for
> now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Martin
> Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k2_bwg0z\hdbscan_9b50b30873a2465bb3156fb27111abf2\hdbscan\_prediction_utils.pyx
>         tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
>       cythoning hdbscan/dist_metrics.pyx to hdbscan\dist_metrics.c
>       C:\Users\Martin Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cn18pe9m\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369:
> FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for
> now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\Martin
> Kunth\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k2_bwg0z\hdbscan_9b50b30873a2465bb3156fb27111abf2\hdbscan\dist_metrics.pxd
>         tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
>       building 'hdbscan._hdbscan_tree' extension
>       error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
>       [end of output]
>       
>       note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
>       ERROR: Failed building wheel for hdbscan
>     ERROR: Could not build wheels for hdbscan, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I don't know now how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 9):

You can solve this problem by installing `python-dev`

```
python3 -m pip install python-dev-tools --user --upgrade
```

Also, try to use  `conda install` instead of `pip`

```
conda install -c conda-forge hdbscan
```

Moreover, make sure that you install `Microsoft Visual C++`

Comment: Thank you. I was able to install python-dev but hdbscan using ``conda install -c conda-forge hdbscan`` gives me ``failed to create a process``

Comment: Update pip `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` and use `conda install -c conda-forge hdbscan`

Comment: Also, try to use `pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan.git#egg=hdbscan` after you make sure that you install the dependencies from [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan)

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that [`top2vec`][1] can give you the same error as it is dependent on `hdbscan`.


  [1]: https://top2vec.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Top2Vec.html

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, and using

```
hdbscan==0.8.32
```

instead of

```
hdbscan==0.8.29
```

fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

It might be a completely different problem, but I had similar issues installing BERTopic and hdbscan, in my case primarily using the terminal in VS Code. I knew I'd had it working previously and assumed it was because I switched from conda to pip, but in the end I got the pip install version working just by accessing my VS Code editor with administrator privileges (i.e. "Run as administrator").

We'd had a company policy change earlier in the year which I think prevented my regular user from installing the thing correctly, which I'm guessing is why it originally worked.

Comment: I also got this problem while installing bertopic, updating my python to 3.11.4 (latest version at the time) fixed it.

Answer (score -2):

After getting the same error, I have managed to install top2vec by following the following steps:

1. `conda install -c conda-forge hdbscan`
2. `conda update -n base -c defaults conda`
3. `pip install top2vec`

Comment: didn't get the context.